# Visual studio coderunner extension does not work. Nothing happens when clicking on run

Tags: python, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Coderunner extension for visual studio code used to work on my computer. Then, for no reason it stopped working. Whenever I press run, nothing happens. No execution, no output to the terminal, nothing. Absolutely nothing happens. I have searched the entire internet for my problem but no one has the same problem as me. I reinstalled visual studio code and coderunner extension but the issue persisted. Anyone with technical knowledge knows how to fix this ?

[image: Nothing happens when I click on run]

There can't be anything wrong with the extension configurations because I imported the extension configurations from an account on another computer which the coderunner worked perfect on. So my computer has the same extension settings for coderunner as that other computer and it still does not work to run coderunner on my computer.

Comment: can you add more details, please? like coderunner version, screenshot, steps you did, just to let the other identify the issue and help you.

Comment: is there anything running on the command line? Did you configure the coderunner commands in settings.json? Please post more details

Comment: I rolled back your edit; your question should remain strictly a question. You are more than welcome to post your solution as an answer, and eventually accept it. (Accepting an answer is how you mark something as solved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by installing an older version of coderunner.

[image]

However, I am not satisfied with this solution. I should not have to use an outdated version of coderunner to make it able to work when there is newer better version of coderunner.
So if anyone knows how I can make it work with newer version of coderunner, feel free to answer.